# Maximum RAM possible in NodeJS Addon

Tags: c++, node.js, ram

I am building a nodejs addon (C and C++) for speech recognition. Every speech request will need approx 30MB of RAM to allocate, acoustic models, language models, etc. I want to know the max of RAM that I am allowed to use. 
I am asking this because after the 6th request (in task manager is equivalent +/- of 175,000k) the nodejs automatically exit.

Note: I am using 32bit version of nodejs in windows7 34 bits.

Comment: How does it exit? Is there an error message? Have you tried running it in a debugger?

Comment: No error message, no breaks,  no alerts. The program just has a peaceful exit and allow me to run it again. I can do 6 recognitions without problem. The thing is I have not implemented some routine to clean the memory after each recognition, so this is my major suspect

Answer (score -1):

[Currently](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/wiki/FAQ), by default v8 has a memory limit of 512MB on 32-bit systems, and 1.4GB on 64-bit systems. The limit can be raised by setting --max_old_space_size to a maximum of ~1024 (~1 GB) (32-bit) and ~4096 (~4GB) (64-bit), but it is recommended that you split your single process into several workers if you are hitting memory limits.

increasing the memory limit in node.js:

```
node --max-old-space-size=1024 my-node-script.js #increase to 1gb
node --max-old-space-size=2048 my-node-script.js #increase to 2gb
node --max-old-space-size=3072 my-node-script.js #increase to 3gb
node --max-old-space-size=4096 my-node-script.js #increase to 4gb
node --max-old-space-size=5120 my-node-script.js #increase to 5gb
node --max-old-space-size=6144 my-node-script.js #increase to 6gb
node --max-old-space-size=7168 my-node-script.js #increase to 7gb
node --max-old-space-size=8192 my-node-script.js #increase to 8gb
```